# Create PDF file using php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm using php & mysql.

I want to retrieve all the records from a table in the database and print them into pdf file.

I write some code but it retrieves only the first record in the table and not retrieved all the other records.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
    or die("Failed to connect to the server: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Users") 
    or die("Failed to connect to the database: " . mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservations");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0)
{
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $db_id       = $result['id'];
        $db_fname    = $result['fname'];
        $db_lname    = $result['lname'];
        $db_email    = $result['email'];
        $db_phone    = $result['phone'];
        $db_day      = $result['day'];
        $db_time     = $result['time'];
        $db_cartype  = $result['car_type'];
        $db_carcolor = $result['car_color'];
        $db_carmodel = $result['car_year'];
        $db_carno    = $result['car_no'];
        $db_problem  = $result['problem'];
        $db_status   = $result['status'];
        $db_remtime  = $result['remaining_time'];
        $db_cost     = $result['cost'];
        $db_payment  = $result['payment'];
        $db_date     = $result['date'];

        require("FPDF/fpdf.php");
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","15");
        $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Freedom Car: Total Reservations",1,1,"C");
        $pdf->Image("porchue.jpg");
        $pdf->SetFont("Arial","","10");
        $pdf->Write(5,"ID: $db_id\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"First Name: $db_fname\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Last Name: $db_lname\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Email Address: $db_email\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Phone Number: $db_phone\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Reserved Day: $db_day\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Reserved Time: $db_time\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Type: $db_cartype\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Color: $db_carcolor\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Model: $db_carmodel\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Number: $db_carno\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Problem: $db_problem\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Status: $db_status\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Remaining Time: $db_remtime\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Total Cost: $db_cost\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Payment Method: $db_payment\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Reservation Date: $db_date\n\n");
        $pdf->Output();
    }
}
else
    echo "<h4>Sorry, No reservations at this time.</h4>";
?>
```

Comment: look at what should and shouldn't be inside that while loop

Comment: I don't understand you, please explain your idea in code not in just some text. @Dagon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you need to create an array and set all data to the array after that 
make your  `$pdf->Write();` comment work.
you cannot write like this because all data in while.

```
 while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
// create an array or call all data here !
}
// use forachone array i main kame loop and start your code.
```

it retrieves only the first record because you need to get all data set once !
but you writepdf commant in the while loop so it retrieves only the first data and cannot pass to another data.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
    or die("Failed to connect to the server: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Users") 
    or die("Failed to connect to the database: " . mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservations");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0)
{
    require("FPDF/fpdf.php");
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","15");
        $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Freedom Car: Total Reservations",1,1,"C");
        $pdf->Image("porchue.jpg");
        $pdf->SetFont("Arial","","10");
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $db_id       = $result['id'];
        $db_fname    = $result['fname'];
        $db_lname    = $result['lname'];
        $db_email    = $result['email'];
        $db_phone    = $result['phone'];
        $db_day      = $result['day'];
        $db_time     = $result['time'];
        $db_cartype  = $result['car_type'];
        $db_carcolor = $result['car_color'];
        $db_carmodel = $result['car_year'];
        $db_carno    = $result['car_no'];
        $db_problem  = $result['problem'];
        $db_status   = $result['status'];
        $db_remtime  = $result['remaining_time'];
        $db_cost     = $result['cost'];
        $db_payment  = $result['payment'];
        $db_date     = $result['date'];


        $pdf->Write(5,"ID: $db_id\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"First Name: $db_fname\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Last Name: $db_lname\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Email Address: $db_email\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Phone Number: $db_phone\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Reserved Day: $db_day\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Reserved Time: $db_time\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Type: $db_cartype\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Color: $db_carcolor\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Model: $db_carmodel\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Number: $db_carno\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Problem: $db_problem\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Car Status: $db_status\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Remaining Time: $db_remtime\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Total Cost: $db_cost\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Payment Method: $db_payment\n");
        $pdf->Write(5,"Reservation Date: $db_date\n\n");
    }
        $pdf->Output();
}
else
    echo "<h4>Sorry, No reservations at this time.</h4>";
?>
```

Comment: I review my code and discovered the problem. thank you sir for your help. checking while loop was the problem. and this is the answer.

@Dagon my welcomes to you from egypt.